# Android studio 2.0 preview 4, cannot not find jni function

Tags: android, android-ndk

[image]

this project can build & run,but c file always show Cannot find 'jni.h'.
other jni function also not found.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you have ndk.dir in local.properties file? Do you have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'` in your top-level **build.gradle**?

Comment: @AlexCohn local.properties automatically adds this line.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Android Studio automatically adds `com.android.tools.build.gradle:1.5.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the bug in Androind Studio 2.0 Preview, please wait for the bugfix.

[Issue 195483: Android Studio cannot find jni.h, but compilation still works.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-rc1'` instead of `0.8.0-alpha3`.
I got a same problem on Android Studio 2.1.2, I tried another version, it works.Sorry for my bad English, hope it can help you :)

Comment: Confirming that this still seems to be the solution. I tried 0.8.0-alpha7 and ran into the same problem. Switching ti 0.7.0-rc1 seems to be the fix for now.